# Excel - how to create new column at empty cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I have been sent an Excel file of an export table of our contacts. However,  all details have been exported into a single column:

Example

```
User 1
User 1 Title
Address
User 1 ID


User 2
User 2 Title
Address
User 2 ID
```

and so on for several thousand rows.

What I need is to convert it into a table.

Is it possible that at every empty cell to create a new column?

I have tried the [answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/866127/excel-split-long-column-into-multiple-columns-by-empty-cell) but I am getting `run time error 6`.

I do not know if it is because I have 4 or 5 empty cells in a row or whether I have done something else wrong.

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: When you get  `run time error 6` click on the "debug" button and let us know what code Excel was trying to execute...

Comment: Hi Mark. endIndex = ActiveCell.Row

at row 32768 which is just an empty row

Answer (score 2):

Change the

```
Dim firstCellRow As Integer
```

to

```
Dim firstCellRow As Long
```

An integer can hold values from -32767 to to 32768 and your spreadsheet likely has over 32,768 rows.

The following should also be changed from Integer to Long:

```
Dim startIndex As Integer
Dim endIndex As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer

...

Dim deleteFrom As Long
Dim deleteTo As Long
```